# Enable properties only for testing in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, properties-file, spring-boot-test

I try to create a special bean only for testing and use of it special properties.

I have `application.yml` and `application-test.yml` files: the properties for testing I would like to keep only in the second one.

I have created a special test configuration file but the spring boot context cannot be started because it cannot find the same properties in the `application.yml`.

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(
    TestProperties::class
)
class TestPropertiesConfiguration

@ConfigurationProperties("test")
data class TestProperties(
    val property1: String,
    val property2: String
)
```

application-test.yml:

```
test:
  property1: value
  property2: value
```

(spring boot expects the same properties also to be in the general `application.yml` file)

Is it possible to have some special properties exactly for testing?

Answer (score 2):

Put a copy of `application.yml` with desired test properties in your `src/test/resources` directory.

Comment: then every time when I want to change something global for all the active profiles, i need to update both application.xml -- a test one and the real one?

Comment: It depends, there are cases when you want to change things only on test environment. But if you need to update them both, you should do so.

Answer (score 0):

edit: I realise now that I misread your usecase a bit. My solution is applicable for instance if you want to deploy your application to a test environment and need to configure your application for that.

You can accomplish this by using spring profiles. This blog explains everything you need: 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles
If your profile is set to test, your application should automatically use application-test.yml in addition to application.yml. If a property is defined in both application.yml and application-test.yml, it should use the one in application-test.yml

Comment: yes, I use different profiles as I wrote in my question. But it does not allow the application-test.yml to have its own properties not mentioned in application.yml

Comment: strange. If your profile is set to test, it should just automatically pick up application-test.yml. I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: it takes the values from application-test.yaml, but if the attributes are not present in application.yml it cannot build the context.
but I need these attributes only for the test stage.